# Change directory and then chain (`exec`) a command?

Tags: shell-script

Is there a command to run an arbitrary command in a specific directory?

In Debian 10, I could simply use [`env --chdir`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/coreutils/env.1.en.html).  However, `env --chdir` is not available on my Debian 9 install.

Part of the command I want to run is composed using shell variables, which could contain spaces or other special characters.  For example, imagine the command I want to run is:

```
strace -- "$@"
```

Therefore, the following would not work:

```
sudo -i sh -c 'cd my-directory && exec strace -- "$@"'
```

---

### uh, why do you want to do this?

I want to use `sudo -i` / `sudo --login` to run a command.  But I want to run the command in a specific directory, not the home directory of the root user.  Although `sudo` can set environment variables, it does not appear to have an option to change directory.

I am using `sudo -i` because: 1) I want the program I am running (my Ansible playbook) to have `HOME=/root`, which will avoid the program creating root-owned files in my home directory. 2) This sounded like an example of a family of problems with `sudo` without `-i`; an entirely fresh environment sounded like the most principled way to solve my problem.

Comment: It is not clear what you are wanting to do with `exec` and `sudo`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor ignoring the `sudo` part, I want to implement `env --chdir` in shell, because `env --chdir` is not available.

Comment: You will have to elaborate. My `env` does not have that option.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor https://manpages.debian.org/buster/coreutils/env.1.en.html

Answer (score 3):

I will ignore `exec` and `-i` as it is not clear what you are asking with respect to these.

However to `cd` and `sudo`, then

```
( cd «a directory»; sudo «a command» )
```

The parenthesis `()` create a sub-shell, `cd` is a built-in, then the command `sudo` or whatever. So process count is same as `env`. `sudo` also manipulates environment variables, so may not be a need for `env` and `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily write a separate script called `chdir`:

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=$1 &&
shift &&
cd -- "$dir" &&
exec "$@"
```

Without a separate script, it is rather more obscure:

```
sh -c 'cd -- "$1" && shift && exec "$@"' sh my-directory "$@"
```

---

However, this did not fulfil the real goal explained in the question.  You might think you can use the above script and run `sudo --login chdir my-directory ...`.  That probably works most of the time, but I think it is a bad idea.  Looking at `man sudo`:

> `-i`, `--login`
>
> Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific resource
>   files such as .profile, .bash_profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell
>   for execution via the shell's `-c` option.

`sh -c` takes a single string parameter.  So how well this works, would depend on how well `sudo` manages to match the quoting conventions of your users shell.  Shell quoting is pretty horrible.

In practice, when I was experimenting with this, I found *something* weird can happen.  Analyses by others suggest the quoting by `sudo` can be "surprising" or "horrible".  See: ["sh -c" does not expand positional parameters, if I run it from "sudo --login". Is there a way around this?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535925/sh-c-does-not-expand-positional-parameters-if-i-run-it-from-sudo-login)

Here is an alternative way to achieve my real goal.  It doesn't require creating a separate script file, but we can wrap it up nicely as a shell function:

```
run_as_root() {
    sudo --set-home \
         bash -l \
              -c 'exec "$@"' \
              bash \
              "$@" 
}
```

Explanation:

- `sudo --set-home` - Run a command as another user.  Some environment is changed, but others are preserved.  Force `HOME` to be set to the new users home directory.
- `bash -l` - Run a "login shell", which initializes the environment.  This assumes your `root` user has not been customized to use a different shell from `bash`.
- `bash -c 'inline shell script' arg0 arg1 arg2...` - Run a small shell script.  `$0` is set to `arg0`, `$1` is set to `arg1`, etc.  Note `$0` is special.  The shell treats `$0` as its own name.  When the shell prints an error message, the error message starts with `$0:`.  Therefore, we should set `arg0` to `bash`.
- `exec` - Replace the shell process with another program.
- `"$@"` - expands to `"$1" "$2" ...`