# "sh -c" does not expand positional parameters, if I run it from "sudo --login". Is there a way around this?

Tags: shell-script, sudo

I wrote an "inline script" which uses positional parameters, e.g.

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "p0=$0" && echo "p1=$1" && echo "p2=$2" && echo "all=$@"' sh 1 2
p0=sh
p1=1
p2=2
all=1 2
```

I actually want to run my inline script using `sudo --login`.  But then the positional parameters don't work.  Is there a way to make them work?

(I'm also interested if the behaviour is documented or standardized somewhere).

```
$ sudo --login sh -c 'echo "p0=$0" && echo "p1=$1" && echo "p2=$2" && echo "all=$@"' sh 1 2
p0=-bash
p1=
p2=
all=1 2
```

Software versions:

```
$ sh --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ sudo --version
Sudo version 1.8.27
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.27
Sudoers file grammar version 46
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.27
```

Comment: `sudo -i` is essentially running it with the user's shell. It's as if the whole thing was wrapped in `bash -c`. Wrap your own command in `bash -c` and maybe some mess of quoting might work.

Comment: @muru I see, yes. Thanks. I was rather hoping to avoid quoting messes :-).

Comment: @muru I used `strace -f -e trace=execve`, and found you were right that sudo is wrapping everything into a single string, to call `bash --login -c '...'`.  Although, that doesn't tell us exactly why the values can be seen in `"$@"`, but not `$1` or `$2`. (And then I checked further; they are also not in `$3` nor `$4` nor `$5` nor `$6`).

Comment: if you want to avoid a mess of quoting (and escaping), just write a shell script and run it with sudo.  It'll be a lot easier to write and to debug than trying to do it on the command-line, even if it's just a one-use throwaway script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the same reason

```
sudo --login echo '$HOME'
```

Doesn't output `$HOME`, but the content of the `$HOME` variable (of the target user, as set by `sudo`).

In your case, it's not because *sh -c doesn't expand the positional parameters*, but because the `$0`, `$1`, `$2` were already expanded (by the login shell) by the time `sh` was started.

What is more surprising here is why you see `all=1 2`. And it's the same reason why you see `$@` upon `sudo --login echo '$@'`.

Both `-s`/`--shell` and `-i`/`--login` run a shell to run the command. But `sudo` does it in a very strange way.

I'd expect `sudo -s 'some shell code'` to run a shell to interpret `some shell code`, but that's not what it does. With `-s`, it still kind-of expects to run a single simple command, and tries to quote (with `\`) some characters in the hope of making it happen through that shell.

You're not meant to do `sudo -s 'echo test'`, but `sudo -s echo test`. In the first case, sudo actually passes `echo\ test` as shell code. In Bourne-like shells, that tries to run a command called `'echo test'`. With a `rc` shell, that would run a command called `echo\` with `test` as argument.

Beside SPC, there are a few characters that `sudo` escapes. That includes backtick, `;`, `|`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `&`, `=`, `\` but strangely enough, not `$` (or maybe that's the only raison d'être of those `-s`/`--login` options: to have a shell expand variables).

It does include `@` though. If you look at [the code](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/b4f31dbe3109/src/parse_args.c#l575), it escapes all bytes except the ASCII alnums, `_`, `-` and `$`.

> ```
>  if (!isalnum((unsigned char)*src) && *src != '_' && *src != '-' && *src != '$')
>    *dst++ = '\\';
> ```

So:

```
sudo -s echo '$@'
```

`sudo` actually runs `"$SHELL" -c 'echo $\@'` and that explains why in your example, `$@` is not expanded by the shell started by `sudo --login`  but by the one you tell it to run.

In your

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "p0=$0" && echo "p1=$1" && echo "p2=$2" && echo "all=$@"' sh 1 2
```

`sudo` runs `root`'s login shell (`bash` in your case) and tells it to interpret:

```
sh -c echo\ \"p0\=$0\"\ \&\&\ echo\ \"p1\=$1\"\ \&\&\ echo\ \"p2\=$2\"\ \&\&\ echo\ \"all\=$\@\" sh 1 2
```

The arguments have been joined with spaces and all the SPC, `"`, `=`, `&`, `@` characters, but not `$` have been escaped. Because those `$` have not been escaped that bash login shell will expand `$0`, `$1`, `$2` but not `$\@` because of that backslash.

You can see it with:

```
$ SHELL=echo sudo -s sh -c 'echo "p0=$0" && echo "p1=$1" && echo "p2=$2" && echo "all=$@"' sh 1 2
-c sh -c echo\ \"p0\=$0\"\ \&\&\ echo\ \"p1\=$1\"\ \&\&\ echo\ \"p2\=$2\"\ \&\&\ echo\ \"all\=$\@\" sh 1 2
```

So that login `bash` shell ends up running `sh` with `-c` as first argument,

```
echo "p0=-bash" && echo "p1=" && echo "p2=" && echo "all=$@"
```

as second argument and `sh`, `1`, `2` as 3rd, 4th and 5th.

To work around it, you can use `${0}` instead of `$0`, because `sudo` transforms it to `$\{0\}` which prevents the login shell from expanding it to the content of *its* `$0`:

```
$ sudo --login sh -c 'echo "p0=${0}" && echo "p1=${1}" && echo "p2=${2}" && echo "all=${@}"' sh 1 2
p0=sh
p1=1
p2=2
all=1 2
```

### Edit: history brings light to the reason behind it

more findings while looking at the code. The non-escaping of `$` was apparently introduced in 2013 [by this change](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/17542d52f714). Which refers to [bug#564](https://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=564) which refers to [bug#413](https://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=413).

It looks like before that bug#413 was *"fixed"*, `sudo` behaved as I expected.

That is:

```
sudo -i 'some shell code'
```

Had the login shell interpret that shell code (and `sudo -s 'some shell code'` had `$SHELL` interpret that shell code). But the bug#413 resolution broke it, because the person who reported the bug didn't understand it worked that way. And the bug#564 broke it further (in an attempt to revert only part of the breakage introduced by the bug#413 resolution).

I went as far as compiling `sudo` 1.7.1 from 2009 and the `-s`/`-i` options were working as I'd expect then. `1.7.3` (with bug#413 resolution) worked kind of like you apparently expected:

```
$ sudo-1.7.1 -i 'echo "$SHELL"'
/bin/bash
$ sudo-1.7.3 -i 'echo "$SHELL"'
-bash: echo "$SHELL": command not found
$ sudo-1.8.21p2 -i 'echo "$SHELL"'
-bash: echo "/bin/bash": No such file or directory
```

```
$ sudo-1.7.3 -i sh -c 'echo "p0=$0" && echo "p1=$1" && echo "p2=$2" && echo "all=$@"' sh 1 2
p0=sh
p1=1
p2=2
all=1 2
```

That escaping introduced in the fix for that bug#413 is easily fooled because banging a `\` in front of all bytes (not character) doesn't work for all.

Beside the obvious case of `rc` where `\` is not even a quoting operator, in most shells, newline can't be quoted with `\`:

```
$ SHELL=sh sudo -s echo $'a\nb'
ab
$ SHELL=csh  sudo -s echo $'a\nb'
a b
```

It also means empty arguments are discarded:

```
$ sudo printf '<%s>\n' a '' b
<a>
<>
<b>
$ sudo -s printf '<%s>\n' a '' b
<a>
<b>
```

Also, by inserting a `\` before every *byte*, it's transforming characters into others in charsets where byte 0x5c (the encoding of `\`) is found in other characters:

```
$ SHELL=bash LC_ALL=zh_HK.big5hkscs sudo -s echo $'\xa3``uname`\xa3`'
bash: line 2: Linuxα: command not found
α
```

0xa3 0x60 is Greek Epsilon in that locale. And sudo changes the 0x60s to 0x5c 0x60 and 0xa3 0x5c is Greek Alpha, which explains why the `uname` command was run. `sudo` changed the

```
ε`uname`ε
```

to

```
\α`\`uname\`\α`
```

And of course the behaviour ends up being surprising in that the `$-`, `$$`, positional parameters and `$varname` (where `varname` is a valid POSIX variable name) are expanded but not the other parameters (like `$@` here, but also `$!`, `$?`, `$*`, `$#`) or `${varname}` or `$var[1]` (`csh`/`tcsh`/`zsh`) or `$var(1)` (`rc`/`es`/...).

Comment: Ow, that's horrible. What do they propose to "fix" with quoting the arguments?

Comment: Answer accepted, in the spirit of "sudo does it in a very strange way". I do not guarantee that `sudo` on my system does everything written (or implied?) in this answer, as per my comment "I was rather hoping to avoid quoting messes :-)".

Comment: @Kusalananda, I never understood why sudo handled `-s`/`--login` that way. To me, it makes it pointless.

Comment: @Kusalananda, see edit with the historical context that explains the current mess.