# How can I keep sudo -i command from changing current directory?

Tags: bash, sudo

`sudo -i COMMAND` runs `COMMAND` in the `$HOME` of root.

This causes an error when I try to run a script of current directory:

```
$ sudo -i ./myscript.sh
-bash: ./myscript.sh: No such file or directory
```

cannot find /home/user/myscript.sh because sudo -i command moves current directory to /root in my case.

How can I make `sudo -i` command keep the current directory?

`sudo` and `sudo -i` have different env, and it needs the env of `sudo -i`

Comment: Why do you need the `-i`? Why can't you just run `sudo ./myscript`?

Comment: `sudo` and `sudo -i` have different env, and it needs the env of `sudo -i`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you need. Using `sudo -i` like that doesn't make much sense, so we need to understand why you think that is the solution. Can't you just run `sudo -i /home/user/myscript.sh`? More importantly, why would you need root's login environment?

Comment: @yoon, I edited to add that comment in to the question, since it seems rather an important point as to why you're doing this. In general, you can [edit] to add clarifications to the question itself. (Information in comments can be missed easily.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't; changing the directory is part of what `sudo -i` does. But you can just go back to where you were and then run the command:

```
sudo -i sh -c "cd '$PWD'; ./myscript.sh"
```

That will fail if `$PWD` contains single quotes. <sub>(On the other hand, if you **know** `$PWD` doesn't contain whitespace, or anything special to the shell, you could nix the single quotes too.)</sub>

A safer way would be something like below:

```
sudo -i sh -c 'cd "${1}"; ./myscript.sh' sh "$PWD"
```

(A plain `"$1"` doesn't work as you'd expect, because `sudo -i` runs the user's login shell in between, leading to another round of expansions. It tries to escape the command to prevent those expansions, but fails for `$1` (and `$foo` etc.). See ["sh -c" does not expand positional parameters, if I run it from "sudo --login". Is there a way around this?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/535925/170373) for the gory details.)

---

In any case, if that script is a tool commonly run by root, it would make sense to put it in some directory that's both in `PATH` for root, *and* only writable by `root`. In general, it's best to avoid any chance of non-root users messing up with what `root` runs, though if it's e.g. in your regular account's home directory, the possible issues are likely minimal.

Comment: @fra-san, aargh, that's even worse than I thought (I can't remember if I've seen that Q&A before, I must have repressed the memory.) Thanks for the link!

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed. One more thing please. I want `alias sudo='sudo -i'`, however, this occurs the above issue. So I tried with `alias sudo="sudo -i sh -c 'cd ${1}' sh '$PWD'"`, but this doesn't work. Any recommendation for this?

Comment: @yoon, it doesn't work directly like that. You _could_ fix that inner `sh` to run the rest of the arguments as a command, but, what with the way `sudo -i` works differently from `sudo` without `-i`, the extra in-between shell and quoting to try to undo what that shell does (without exactly succeeding)... I wouldn't go there.

Comment: @yoon, instead, it might be a better idea to have `./myscript.sh` and whatever others you use like that, to set up their environment as needed, without having to deal with `sudo -i`

Comment: It's the best for me to set an alias because I use sudo not only for script file but also for directly typed(interactive?) commands. I think `alias sudo="sudo -i sh -c 'cd ${1}' sh '$PWD'; sh "` works as I expect.

Comment: Ah, no,,, Running scripts works well, but `$ sudo printenv PATH` prints
 `/usr/bin/printenv: /usr/bin/printenv: cannot execute binary file`. I need more works,,

Comment: @yoon are you just looking for `sudo -s`? Please ask a new question and explain what you are trying to do and exactly what your requirements are. That alias is needlessly complicated (and wrong, you can't `sh '$PWD'`) but if you explain what you need, I am sure we can give you a good solution.

Comment: I've also checked with `sudo -s` but it doesn't seem to work as I expected. Okay, I just opened a new question. Thanks. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/642814/sudo-s-env-vs-sudo-i-env

Comment: @terdon, well, `sudo -i` runs a login shell, so (assuming Bash) it reads e.g. the target's `.profile` etc. A non-login shell would read `.bashrc`. And a noninteractive shell (like with `sudo -s somecmd`) would read neither. Other than that, you're not wrong, there would probably be a better way to set up the environment for the script (or scripts).

Comment: @yoon, but yeah, is there something in particular you need from the login environment? Some environment variables or such?

Comment: Yes, I'm running a hadoop cluster, and certain commands should be run with customized PATH variable, not the defaults.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid having `sudo -i` change your home directory, don't use the `-i` flag,

```
sudo ./myscript.sh
```

The documentation for `sudo` (see `man sudo`) states of the `-i` flag (with my emphasis)

> **`-i`**, **`--login`**
> Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as `.profile`, `.bash_profile` or `.login` will be read by the shell. [...] **`sudo` attempts to change to that user's home directory before running the shell.** The command is run with an environment similar to the one a user would receive at log in.

Your question's just been edited to say you need your root profile to the run the script. Without knowing what environment it is that you need the closest I can offer is this

```
sudo -i "${PWD:-$(pwd)}/myscript.sh"
```

If you know the actual location of `myscript.sh` (for example, it's in your home directory) you would be better providing that directly,

```
sudo -i "$HOME/myscript.sh"
```

There may be better options but you would need to provide details of the environment you need set up