# "sudo -s env" vs "sudo -i env"

Tags: sudo

`sudo -s printenv PATH` and `sudo -i printenv PATH` show different result.

`sudo -s printenv PATH` prints just the same as `sudo printenv PATH`.

According to man page, `-i` option sources to set PATH variable.

> This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile, .bash_profile or .login will be read by the shell.

About `-s` option, it says:

> Run the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell specified by the invoking user's password database entry.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c
> option.  If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.

Does `Run the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set`  mean that I can bash profile files when executing commands with `sudo -s`?

I need `sudo -s` to have the same env variables as `sudo -i`, but I cannot use `sudo -i` because it changes directory.

---

Edited:

/etc/profile.d/ENV_FILE

```
if ! echo ${PATH} | /bin/grep -q /usr/customized/bin ; then
        PATH=/usr/customized/bin:${PATH}
fi
if ! echo ${PATH} | /bin/grep -q /usr/customized/sbin ; then
        if [ `/usr/bin/id -u` = 0 ] ; then
                PATH=/usr/customized/sbin:${PATH}
        fi
fi
```

The above file is read, and only root can get the `sbin` path.

And the env file is deployed over the clsuter, so it doesn't seem to be reasonable to touch that env file.

This is why I need env variables that are obtained with `sudo -i`, which reads the above env file as a root user.